# how to clear parent inverse without actually moving the object

Tags: python

In Blender, a parent-child relationship stores the relationship between the 2 objects created when parenting.

This is normally OK, but in some cases its useful to have a reset loc/rot/scale, align the child exactly with its parent.

I need to reset those extra matrices in blender object - I have an object that is perfectly aligned with it's parent, but the euler rotations values say something very different. I need a script to have this object's rotation at 0,0,0 (or, potentially other value, which expresses the real rotation offset to it's parent)

Answer (score 10):

You can reset the parent inverse matrix, then apply the relationship between the original matrix and the parents onto the child object.

*This script assumes you have the child selected.*

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object

# Store a copy of the objects final transformation
# so we can read from it later.
ob_matrix_orig = ob.matrix_world.copy()

# Reset parent inverse matrix.
# (relationship created when parenting)
ob.matrix_parent_inverse.identity()

# Re-apply the difference between parent/child
# (this writes directly into the loc/scale/rot) via a matrix.
ob.matrix_basis = ob.parent.matrix_world.inverted() @ ob_matrix_orig
```

---

Note, if the child has any *shearing* because of rotation and the parents non-uniform scaling, that will be removed, since loc/scale/rot can't represent shearing.

Comment: The matrix multiplication on the last line doesn't seem to work in Blender 2.80, seems like something changed.

Comment: Updated for  2.8x

Comment: I went ahead and implemented this as a blender plugin for both 2.79 and 2.80+, if anyone is interested. https://github.com/drewcassidy/blender-apply-parent-inverse