# How to store multiple added empties IDs used in a warp modifier so they don't conflict with new warp modifiers?

Tags: scripting, modifiers

this is my first time coding for Blender, I haven't gotten around to organizing the code yet. I'm self taught so my code's not the cleanest.

I'm attempting to create a 'dorito' deformer using this code, by selecting a vertex and running this script, it would create two empties that would be used for a warp modifier that would be added to the selected object.  I am using bmesh to access the selected vertex's coordinates so I could add the empties to that location, storing it into the "vertex" variable.

I am storing the return value of the empties to an empty list, but I don't know how to use that to be able to add more empties to a second or third warp modifier making the script actually useful.

Any input is appreciated!

PS: I am scripting this for 2.92.  Just in case there are relevant changes in the API.

```
import bpy
import bmesh



if bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

object_data = bpy.context.object.data
meObject = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(object_data)


bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = meObject


if bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')





#gets vertex position to add empties
vertex = (0,0,0)
for v in bm.verts:
    if v.select:
        vertex = tuple(v.co)

#changes mode
if bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

#empties list to store empties
empties = []

#adds first empty for warp deformer,  and appends to list
empties.append(bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(vertex), scale=(2, 2, 2)))
#names empty added
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'Parent'

#sets parent name
bpy.context.object.parent = meObject

#adds second empty for warp deformer
empties.append(bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(vertex), scale=(1, 1, 1)))
#names empty added
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'Deformer'
#changes empty used
bpy.context.object.empty_display_type = 'CUBE'
bpy.context.object.empty_display_size = 0.75
bpy.context.object.parent = bpy.data.objects["Parent"]



bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = meObject




#adds warp modifier
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='WARP')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Warp"].object_from = bpy.data.objects["Parent"]
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Warp"].object_to = bpy.data.objects["Deformer"]


if bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using API methods.**

A common misapprehension in blender is that create / add "anything" operators return the newly created thing, instead the newly created thing is found from context. Eg for add object primitives the new object is `context.object` directly after the call (if run in OBJECT mode) A newly added modifier sits last in the objects modifiers collection.

That said, it is a lot, lot, lot  easier (IMO) to totally ditch the operators  & instead use related API methods which return a reference.

Below is an operator-less re-rig of question code to run entirely in EDIT mode

- Select a vertex
- Adds a warp modifier, once again using the related API method `new_mod = Object.modifiers.new(...)`, so we have its reference.  The new modifiers show in edit mode is set, so we can see the result.
- Adds two empties, the first is at the location of the vert, the second is offset from the first by the value set for `offset` These are assigned as the "from" and "to" objects of the modifier.
- The empties are given a name to reflect object warping, which modifier, from or to.  Other things to consider would be putting the empties into their own collection.
- Looped over the "object_from", "object_to" properties of the modifier.  `setattr(warp, k, ob)` is equivalent to `warp.object_from = ob` when `k == "object_from"`.
- The offset is in global coordinates. This is converted to local since the empties are being parented to the warping object. Think this answer helps explain the maths used [Which matrix to use to transform children local coordinates to global?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214785/which-matrix-to-use-to-transform-children-local-coordinates-to-global/214796#214796)

Test code.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy import context

offset = Vector((0, 0, 1))


col = context.collection
ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world
mwi = mw.inverted()
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

vert = bm.select_history.active
# if not a vert then throw error
assert(isinstance(vert, bmesh.types.BMVert))

warp = ob.modifiers.new("Warp", type='WARP')
warp.show_in_editmode = True
for k in ("object_from", "object_to"):
    mt = bpy.data.objects.new(f"{warp.name}_{k}", None)
    
    col.objects.link(mt)
    
    if k.endswith("from"): # 
        mt.location = vert.co
    else:
        mt.location = vert.co + mwi @ offset

    setattr(warp, k, mt)
    mt.parent = ob
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!  I'm going to test it out and ask you some things about it, I hope that's alright!